# WAMP Server 3.0.0 cannot open apache conf file

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I've re-installed WAMP in order to put it into a different directory.  This was mainly so everything is automatically backed up.

Mysql starts ok, but apache fails with the following message from the event viewer:

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > httpd.exe: Could not open configuration file bin/conf/httpd.conf: The system cannot find the path specified.     .

This file is in the correct place (C:\googledrive\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf) and there isn't any other stray httpd.conf files that it might be picking up on the path or anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install it or copy it?

Comment: Are you sure there are no references to anything in your PATH that point to the old install location?

Comment: When you installed it, did you run the installation either from an admin account or using the right click on the install.exe and "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Yes I am sure about the references.  I installed it using my normal account which is an admin account on W7

Comment: Ok so look in the Windows Event Viewer as well as the Apache error log for messages from Apache

Comment: Yes, the message in my original post came from Event Viewer as I made clear.  There's nothing in the apache error log

Comment: Erm.... No you did not make that clear. I suppose you did read the message from the install, that suggested all the MSVC runtimes that must be installed?

Comment: Sorry RiggsFolly, my reply was a bit blunt!  I thought I had made it clear with "Mysql starts ok, but apache fails with the following message from the event viewer:"

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a permissions problem.  It seems that the system account didn't have access to the directory containing the config file, but I guess must have had enough access to start up Apache and give that helpful (not) message!